# What's the deal with softwaretalk.info?

Tags: discussion

Softwaretalk.info seems to be serving up Super User content without attribution.

Are they violating a content license?

**Update**

I missed the footer attribution.  Maybe I need new glasses?

Comment: the license is right there at the very bottom

Comment: @SimonSheehan - It certainly is, hence the remark about possibly needing new glasses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stack Exchange content is distributed under the following license:

> user contributions licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

They...

- link to user profiles of both OP and answerers
- Mention that the content is from Stack Exchange (footer: *Content from Superuser of Stack Exchange*)
- Link to the original question (footer: *Original article at Superuser.*)
- None of the links are `nofollow`ed

So they [satisfy the license requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24618/151367).
If they didn't, [we could add them to the list of license offenders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106824/151367).

Comment: +1 … and what are *you* doing on a Saturday this early? :)

Answer (score 5):

Here are the [requirements for attribution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24618/159624):

> Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.

That's fine. They say: "Content from Superuser of Stack Exchange. Original article at Superuser." at the bottom.

> Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site

They do that as well.

> Show the author names for every question and answer

That's in there too, also for the comments.

> Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site

They also took care about that.

---

Therefore, I don't see a particular problem with that site, at least in terms of missing attribution.